# Module not found: Can't resolve react

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to add a SearchBar to my react-native project, but as soon as I add the import, it fails saying Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' along with a bunch of other modules. I've tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, then npm install but it won't resolve the issue.  I've included the js file, package.json, and a portion of the error I'm getting

```js
{
  "name": "gympedia",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```js
import { View, Text , Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { SearchBar } from "@rneui/themed";


const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../../assets/muscle-icon.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        
    
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image style={styles.icons} source={require('../../assets/search-icon.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image style={styles.icons} source={require('../../assets/bookmark-icon.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

```html
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'
> 1 | import { useMemo } from 'react';
  2 | import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
  3 | export const makeStyles = (styles) => (props) => {
  4 |     return useMemo(() => {
../node_modules/@rneui/themed/dist/config/makeStyles.js:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'
> 1 | import { useMemo } from 'react';
  2 | import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
  3 | import { useTheme } from './ThemeProvider';
  4 | export const makeStyles = (styles) => (props = {}) => {
../node_modules/@rneui/base/dist/helpers/index.js:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native'
> 1 | import { Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
  2 | import color from 'color';
  3 | import renderNode from './renderNode';
  4 | import getIconType, { registerCustomIconType } from './getIconType';
../node_modules/@rneui/base/dist/helpers/colors.js:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native'
> 1 | import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
  2 | export const lightColors = {
  3 |     primary: '#2089dc',
  4 |     secondary: '#03dac4',
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be an issue with the @rneui libraries. I would try downgrading those two libraries to a previous version. Just look at the library for the next previous version and do a npm install @rneui/base@version# @reneui/themed@version#. Could also be that you dont have semi colons at the end of two of your imports.

Answer (score 0):

When we import some modules/ dependencies to use in our code (via `npm/yarn install`) the entry of the dependency is made in `package.json` file. So when we use them, those will be referred.
Similarly, lot of the modules that we import are further dependent on other modules for internal handling of their code. So in the same way, each module has their own `package.json` file. 
It seems the entry for modules mentioned in error are not mentioned in the modules `package.json` file. 
To fix this either

- remove the current unstable import, and revert to a stable/older version. OR
- If you want, correct the issues in `package.json` file present in `project_directory/node_modules/{your_module_name}/`. And in the this add the `"devDependencies"` section add your **modules** along with their **versions** used which are missing. And add a `keyword` entry if required